# Why is my simple comparator broken?

Tags: java, sorting, puzzle

I have a class, which I have simplified to this:

```
final class Thing {
    private final int value;
    public Thing(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}
```

I want to sort an array of this thing. So I have created a simple copmarator:

```
private static final Comparator<Thing> reverse = new Comparator<Thing>() {
    public int compare(Thing a, Thing b) {
        return a.getValue() - b.getValue();
    }
};
```

I then use the two argument form of `Arrays.sort`.

This works fine for my test cases, but sometimes it goes all wrong with the array ending up in a strange but repeatable order. 
How can this be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Integer overflow… or more precisely, underflow.

Instead, do an explicit comparison:

```
private static final Comparator<Thing> reverse = new Comparator<Thing>() {
    public int compare(Thing a, Thing b) {
      int av = a.getValue(), bv = b.getValue();
      return (av == bv) ? 0 : ((av < bv) ? -1 : +1);
    }
};
```

Using subtraction is fine if you are sure that the difference won't "wrap around". For example, when the values in question are constrained to be non-negative.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot use minus to create the comparison.  You'll overflow when the absolute difference exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Instead, use this algorithm:

```
int compareInts( int x, int y ) {
  if ( x < y ) return -1;
  if ( x > y ) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I like to have this function in a library for such purposes.

Comment: For a moment I was going to point you to the static method in Integer. But it isn't there...

Comment: @Tom: `Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(y);` is the most succinct way I can think of. Strange how Double has the static `compare()` method and the other number types don't.

Comment: @Grundlefleck: True!  But of course my method is much faster to execute because it doesn't create a new `Integer` instance.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_Value - Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

This needs to return a positive number as MAX_VALUE > MIN_VALUE but instead prints -1

Answer (score 5):

When comparing Java primitives, it is advisable to convert them to their Object counterparts and rely on their `compareTo()` methods.

In this case you can do:

```
return Integer.valueOf(a.getValue()).compareTo(b.getValue())
```

When in doubt, use a well-tested library.

Comment: Bit of an overhead there (for non-small values).

Answer (score 3):

What kind of numbers do you throw in there? If your numbers are large enough, you could wrap through the MIN/MAX values for integers and end up in a mess.

Answer (score 2):

If a's value is very negative and b's value is very positive your answer will be very wrong.

IIRC, Int overflow silently wraps around in the JVM

-- MarkusQ